# Issue when searching QTableWidget using wildcards

Tags: c++, qt, search, wildcard, qlineedit

In my Qt C++ application I have several items in a qtablewidget. A `QLineEdit` along with a button are used by me in order to search the `QTableWidget` when a particular word is given to the line edit and the search button is clicked. Following is my code:

```
bool found=false;
QString Line= ui->search->text();

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(ui->tableWidget->item(i,0)->text()== Line){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(found){
    ui->tableWidget->clear();
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(Line));
}
else{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application Name"), tr("The word you are searching does not exist!") );
}
```

This code works if an exact word in the table widget is given but if I use

```
ui->tableWidget->item(i,0)->text()=="%"+ Line+"%";
```

It won't work for the wild card scenario so that I can search even part of a word is given. How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The == operator compare two strings and return true if they are exacly equals.
If you want to use wildcards, I suggest to use `QRegExp` and use `QRegExp::Wildcard` as pattern syntax.

Example 1:

```
QString line = "aaaaLINEbbbb";
QRegExp rx("*LINE*");
rx.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
rx.exactMatch(line); //should return true
```

However, if you want to test only if a string contains a substring, I suggest to use bool `QString::contains(const QString &str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs)` that can be faster.

Example 2:

```
QString line = "aaaaLINEbbbb";
QString searchWord = "LINE";
line.contains(searchWord); //should return true
```

See:

- [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html)
- [QRegExp::PatternSyntax](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#PatternSyntax-enum)
- [Wildcard Matching](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#qregexp-wildcard-matching)
- [QString::contains](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#contains)

Comment: Thanx I actually want to use wild cards!